# Setting up iOS push notification with Google Cloud Messaging and Phonegap Plugin Push

Tags: ios, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am struggling to get GCM to work with my iOS app. I have verified that it does work on the android build, but not the iOS.

I have set up the GCM account, and uploaded my Dev and Prod `.p12` certs.

When initialising the plugin, I get the following output:

```
2016-05-08 18:11:05.657 MyApp[1234:12345678] Push Plugin register called
2016-05-08 18:11:05.658 MyApp[1234:12345678] PushPlugin.register: setting badge to false
2016-05-08 18:11:05.658 MyApp[1234:12345678] PushPlugin.register: clear badge is set to 0
2016-05-08 18:11:05.659 MyApp[1234:12345678] PushPlugin.register: better button setup
2016-05-08 18:11:05.660 MyApp[1234:12345678] GCM Sender ID **********
2016-05-08 18:11:05.660 MyApp[1234:12345678] Using GCM Notification
2016-05-08 18:11:05.695 MyApp[1234:12345678] Push Plugin register success: <**********....>
2016-05-08 18:11:05.790 MyApp[1234:12345678] GCM Registration Token: ******************************************
```

The token appears to be valid, and I am capable of sending messages to that token with the [provided ruby server script](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/example/server/pushGCM.rb).

I get a response that looks like this:

```
[{:response=>"success",
:body=>{"multicast_id"=>******, "success"=>1, "failure"=>0, "canonical_ids"=>0, "results"=>[{"message_id"=>"*******************"}]},
:headers=>
{"content-type"=>["application/json; charset=UTF-8"], "date"=>["Sun, 08 May 2016 18:24:35 GMT"], "expires"=>["Sun, 08 May 2016 18:24:35 GMT"], "cache-control"=>["private, max-age=0"], "x-content-type-options"=>["nosniff"], "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"], "server"=>["GSE"], "alternate-protocol"=>["443:quic"], "alt-svc"=>["quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25\""], "accept-ranges"=>["none"], "vary"=>["Accept-Encoding"], "connection"=>["close"]},
:status_code=>200}]
```

Still, **the message never shows up on my iOS device**. I went into the log of my android app and connected the GCM there, so I could see the status of the message. The messages sendt from my server to the iOS device has a status of "Accepted".

```
Current Status  Accepted
Collapse Key    n/a
TTL 2,419,200
```

As I read the [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en), I believe it should say something like `Accepted, sent to APNS` when it is successfully forwarded to APNS. I have tried to find a solution to this, but I have not yet found one.

Can the problem be that both my Android and iOS app is on the same google app (thus having the same `Server API Key` and the same `Sender ID`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM is implemented using Apple's push notification technology, and when that fails then 99% of the time it is due to a mis-match occurring somewhere in the chain of 4 required items that need to be either all dev or all prod related for it to work.

So you need to determine in your situation if you are using the dev or prod certs and dev or prod token and if you have configured your GMC account to be dev or prod (which will change which gateway GCM uses to send the pushes over). If you check all of these there is hopefully a good chance it will start working correctly.
 Here's some further details:

When push notifications fail to work the reason is almost certainly always due to the fact that the push “equation” has been broken.

There are two equations, either one of which must be followed exactly in order for pushes to work.

The Development equation:

> Development build of the App + Development APN token + Development
>   Certificate + Development Apple gateway == SUCCESS

The Production equation:

> Production build of the App + Production APN token + Production
>   Certificate + Production Apple gateway == SUCCESS.

If you have any dev element in the production equation, or any production element in the development equation then the push will NOT work. 
All four elements of the equation must be either all development or all production.

When you run the app using Xcode it will be a development build of the app by default (it can be changed in the scheme) and thus when using Xcode you must use the development equation for it to work.
If you create an ad-hoc distribution or app store build then it will be a production build and you must use the production equation for it to work.

Also the production build of the app and the development build of the app result in different push tokens, so if you are temporarily hard-coding a token into some server test script or similar, then you must make sure its the correct token.
In older versions of iOS the tokens would effectively never change once you had obtained it (they could, but the circumstances when it would were rare). But in iOS9 this is no longer the case and the token can and does change, so always make sure the token you are using on the server is up to date.

Pushes must also be sent over the correct gateway, the Apple development gateway is the sandbox gateway:

> ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

While the production gateway is:

> ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195

When using the production gateway the server must be signed with the production certificate of course, and signed with the development certificate when using the sandbox gateway.

If you use the same password for both certificates then you can sign your server with both the production certificate and development certificate in the same .pem file. I.e. You can concatenate all the elevate certificates and keys into a single .pem file and use that to sign the server. The server will of course need to use the sandbox gateway when testing using Xcode and the production gateway for the final app store release.

Comment: It is likely that this is the problem. Where can I verify that my tokens are either production or development? I am only give a single `Server API Key`, and a single `Sender ID` as far as I can tell.

Comment: I should have clarified that part. You can't verify what token is which, you just need to make sure if you are collecting the token manual (i.e. temporarily for testing purposes) that you collect it from correct build of the app. Normally the app gets the token programmatically and sends it to the server doing the push all programmatically.

Comment: It does look like this is my problem. I got GCM to forward to APNS now, but somehow it unregisters and the app does not get the notification. I am sure it has to do with different build variations. Thanks for the help.